# How to turn off Laravel 5.8 error reporting in local environment

Tags: laravel, error-logging, laravel-5.8

I'm using Bugsnag for bug reporting and when I'm testing in my local environment all of these exceptions get recorded.

I've done some googling and I'm not seeing anything specific to what I'm trying to accomplish. I've read through the error handling and logging documentation and I didn't see anything there.

Of course, I can exclude the Bugsnag API key in my .env file, but I'd also like to know how to turn off all logging.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off error reporting by changing two variables in .env file like below:
APP_ENV=production 
APP_DEBUG=false

Comment: Hi @mehran N.H,  thanks for the answer! This isn't quite what I'm looking for though. 1, my environment is local and regarding the debug environment variable I still want errors displayed just not reported

Answer (score -1):

Update these variables in .env file as below:

```
APP_ENV=local

APP_DEBUG=false
```

Ensure APP_ENV is local for local developments. When you put it on production, you need to have it as `APP_ENV=production`

It is very dangerous to have `APP_ENV=local` on production servers. You might accidentally do a `php artisan migrate:reset` & your database will go wiped off.

But if you have it as `APP_ENV=production`, it will ask you for the confirmation in the red text before wiping off your database.